# why not custom resources tree display all modules of magento

Tags: magento

I was created different role on magento 1.9 admin panel . give various resources to roles but it does not display all modules on magento custom resources tree . one module is missing there so I cann't give access of that module to role .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: to display any module in the resource list, module must have <acl> tags in its `config.xml`

Comment: acl is includes in config.xml . and it display all options in resources but only one custom option not display .

Comment: @MINAKSHEEAWARI then you need to add acl tag for that option, check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/136254/20064) , it will give you some idea about acl

Comment: can you pls tell me path of acl ?

Comment: @MINAKSHEEAWARI you have to add `<acl>`  tag in `app/code/Your_codePool/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml` file

Comment: I was add acl in admihtml.xml file properly then also I dont get proper result..

Comment: @MINAKSHEEAWARI without seeing code, its hard to find whats wrong

Comment: thank you @Piyush its working